# Is $1 + \lg i = \lg(i + i)$?

Tags: logarithms

I've been studying Sedgewick's "Algorithms" book and in proof of one proposition he writes the following:

> the property is preserved because $1 + \lg i  = \lg(i + i) \le \lg(i + j) = \lg k$

I cannot wrap my brain around the first part of this inequation, namely $1 + \lg i  = \lg(i + i)$.
Can anyone offer an explanation? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $\mathrm{lg}$ function is the [logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) to the base $2$ (or [binary logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_logarithm)), that is, $\mathrm{lg}\, 2=1$. Thus $$\mathrm{lg}\, (i+i)=\mathrm{lg} (2i)=\mathrm{lg}\, 2+\mathrm{lg}\,i=1+\mathrm{lg}\,i$$

By the way, the $\mathrm{lg}$ function can also be defined by $\mathrm{lg}\,(x)=\frac{\log x}{\log 2}$.